# Expression Web Source Control Integration?

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe, expression-web, expression-studio

Does anyone know if Expression Web (and Blend, for that matter) has any form of direct integration with source control?

Right now that's about the only real downside we've discovered in a couple days of using it. But it's a **big** downside.

Quick edit:

Yes, we're currently using the demon spawn Source Safe. (For the record, with the size team and projects we're doing, it actually does suffice and has caused us no pain outside of the occasional build hiccup from lack of transacted check-ins.) However, I don't care a whit about Source Safe itself -- I'm trying to find out if there's any way to get the Expression products to integrate with ANY source control system, whether it be Team Foundation Server, Subversion, ANYTHING. (And yes, we are looking to move away from VSS eventually. If only to stop other Stack'ers from laughing at us. :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is now TFS integreation available for Blend 3: http://blogs.msdn.com/unnir/archive/2009/03/17/team-foundation-server-support-in-blend-3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I tried to bear with you.....but I just can't do it!  I think the time has probably come for you to unshackle yourselves from sourcesafe!

Install subversion, and life will be all good again.

Comment: We're going to move away from the demon spawn, but probably to the source control that's in TFS. (When we can justify installing that bad boy.)

Comment: I think that would be a good plan if things like expression web / blend not having sourcesafe integration is a "big" downside

Comment: Ah-ah-ah ... It's not that they lack SourceSafe integration. They seem to lack ALL SCC integration -- whether it be TFS, VSS, SVN, SCS or what have you. And therein lies the rub.